# How to compare consecutive rows in a matrix column and then change value accordingly

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a matrix full of 1's and 0's. The columns represent samples and the rows represent chromosomes.

I would like to keep all rows that have consecutive 1's in them (ie at least two consecutive rows with a 1 in it). This has to be restricted per chromosome (so that consecutive 1's between two chromosomes is not counted).

I would like to do this for each column in the matrix.

My data is as follows:

```
chr       leftPos     OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1           4324            0            1
1           23433           1            1
1           34436           1            0
1           64755           1            1
3           234             1            0
3           354             0            1
4           1666            0            1
4           4565            0            1
5           34777           1            1
7           2345            1            1
7           4567            1            1
```

and the output should be:

```
chr       leftPos     OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1           4324            0            1
1           23433           1            1
1           34436           1            0
1           64755           1            0
3           234             0            0
3           354             0            0
4           1666            0            1
4           4565            0            1
5           34777           0            0
7           2345            1            1
7           4567            1            1
```

I don't know how to compare consecutive rows according to chromosome. I imagine I could group by dplyr and somehow compare rows but the comparison is a bit beyond me.

**EDIT**

Using dput actual data

```
    structure(list(chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), leftPos = c(240000, 
1080000, 1200000, 1320000, 1440000, 1800000, 2400000, 2520000, 
3120000, 3360000, 3480000, 3600000, 3720000, 4200000, 4560000, 
4920000, 5040000, 5160000, 5280000, 6000000, 7080000, 7200000, 
7320000, 7440000, 7560000, 7680000, 7800000, 8280000, 8400000, 
8520000, 8760000, 9120000, 9720000, 9840000, 9960000, 10080000, 
10200000, 10320000, 10440000, 10560000, 10800000, 11040000, 11160000, 
11280000, 11400000, 11520000, 11760000, 11880000, 12000000, 12120000
), chr.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), leftPos.res = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_026C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), OC_AH_026C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_026C.2.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_084C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_AH_086C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_086C.1.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_086C.2.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_AH_086C.3.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_088C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_094C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_AH_094C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_094C.2.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_094C.3.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_AH_094C.4.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_094C.5.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_094C.6.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_AH_094C.7.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_096C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_100C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_AH_100C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_127C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_AH_133C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_ED_008C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ED_008C.1.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), OC_ED_008C.2.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_ED_008C.3.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ED_016C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ED_031C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_ED_036C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_GS_001C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_QE_062C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_RS_010C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_RS_027C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_RS_027C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_RS_027C.2.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_SH_051C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_014C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_ST_014C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_020C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_024C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_ST_033C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_034C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_034C.1.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), OC_ST_034C.2.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_035C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_ST_036C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_ST_040C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_002C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_005C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), OC_WG_006C.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), OC_WG_019C.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Type.res = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqA.BloodDMets_16AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqB.BloodDMets_13AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqC.BloodDMets_16AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqD.BloodDMets_27AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), Means.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    sd.res = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), count = 1:50), .Names = c("chr", 
"leftPos", "chr.res", "leftPos.res", "OC_AH_026C.res", "OC_AH_026C.1.res", 
"OC_AH_026C.2.res", "OC_AH_084C.res", "OC_AH_086C.res", "OC_AH_086C.1.res", 
"OC_AH_086C.2.res", "OC_AH_086C.3.res", "OC_AH_088C.res", "OC_AH_094C.res", 
"OC_AH_094C.1.res", "OC_AH_094C.2.res", "OC_AH_094C.3.res", "OC_AH_094C.4.res", 
"OC_AH_094C.5.res", "OC_AH_094C.6.res", "OC_AH_094C.7.res", "OC_AH_096C.res", 
"OC_AH_100C.res", "OC_AH_100C.1.res", "OC_AH_127C.res", "OC_AH_133C.res", 
"OC_ED_008C.res", "OC_ED_008C.1.res", "OC_ED_008C.2.res", "OC_ED_008C.3.res", 
"OC_ED_016C.res", "OC_ED_031C.res", "OC_ED_036C.res", "OC_GS_001C.res", 
"OC_QE_062C.res", "OC_RS_010C.res", "OC_RS_027C.res", "OC_RS_027C.1.res", 
"OC_RS_027C.2.res", "OC_SH_051C.res", "OC_ST_014C.res", "OC_ST_014C.1.res", 
"OC_ST_020C.res", "OC_ST_024C.res", "OC_ST_033C.res", "OC_ST_034C.res", 
"OC_ST_034C.1.res", "OC_ST_034C.2.res", "OC_ST_035C.res", "OC_ST_036C.res", 
"OC_ST_040C.res", "OC_WG_002C.res", "OC_WG_005C.res", "OC_WG_006C.res", 
"OC_WG_019C.res", "Type.res", "ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqA.BloodDMets_16AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res", 
"ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqB.BloodDMets_13AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res", 
"ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqC.BloodDMets_16AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res", 
"ZSSLX.10457.FastSeqD.BloodDMets_27AF_AHMMH.s_1.r_1.fq.gz.res", 
"Means.res", "sd.res", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you desire as output. You have kept an identical set of rows, but you changed some 1s to 0s. So this is not about keeping rows, but rather about reassigning non-consecutive 1s to 0?

Comment: Not sure how you are getting the output.

Comment: I guess per column (and per chromosome) he wants to keep the rows with consecutive 1s.

Comment: As per @Ansjovis86 I want to do that exactly- thanks for clarifyng

Comment: @Ken Benoit I guess I meant comparing values in consecutive rows by column. Apologies for lack of clarity

Comment: I guess with some loops on column and chromosome number combined with some if else statements where you check the neighbours of a row, you could get it working. I'm just not sure if that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: So what you want is any series longer than one times a 1? For example if you have 001110. Do you want to include the last 1?

Comment: While the `dput` is appreciated, for future reference, a minimal example does not equal 50 rows and 63 columns. The size of your original example was perfectly fine, why give us all that extra information?

Comment: Apologies. I was asked for it because there are so many zeros that nobody could see how the singleton 1s were getting eradicated. I hate it too...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution applying a function across `chr` values using the `by =` argument to **data.table**.  Non-adjacent sequences are located using `rle()`. Should be fast too.

First, here is the data as I input it:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection( 
"chr       leftPos     OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1           4324            0            1
1           23433           1            1
1           34436           1            0
1           64755           1            1
3           234             1            0
3           354             0            1
4           1666            0            1
4           4565            0            1
5           34777           1            1
7           2345            1            1
7           4567            1            1"), header = TRUE)
```

Then the code to process the result:

```
# function to take an integer vector and make non-consecutive 1s into 0s
convertNonRuns <- function(booleanVec) {
    rleVals <- rle(booleanVec)
    makeZeroIndex1 <- which(rleVals$lengths == 1 & rleVals$values == 1)
    makeZeroIndex2 <- sapply(makeZeroIndex1, function(x) cumsum(rleVals$lengths[1:x])[x])
    if (length(makeZeroIndex2))
        booleanVec[makeZeroIndex2] <- 0L
    as.integer(booleanVec)
}

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
# use data.table's by command to convert runs within chr(omosome)
dt[, c("OC_030_ST.res", "OC_031_WG.res") := 
     list(convertNonRuns(OC_030_ST.res), convertNonRuns(OC_031_WG.res)),
      by = chr]
dt
##     chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
##  1:   1    4324             0             1
##  2:   1   23433             1             1
##  3:   1   34436             1             0
##  4:   1   64755             1             0
##  5:   3     234             0             0
##  6:   3     354             0             0
##  7:   4    1666             0             1
##  8:   4    4565             0             1
##  9:   5   34777             0             0
## 10:   7    2345             1             1
## 11:   7    4567             1             1
```

**Added**

For the newly added dput data, this will work:

```
# select all variables OC*.res
varnamesToChange <- names(dt)[grep("^OC.*\\.res$", names(dt))]
dt[, varnamesToChange := lapply(varnamesToChange, function(x) dt[[x]]), by = chr]
```

I am using **data.table** version 1.9.6.

Comment: When I run this I still get a few 1's on their own in the column. If they on their own they should be converted to zero.

Comment: I just reran it and it worked fine, as per the above output.

Comment: Oh I'm getting this error Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(c("OC_AH_026C.1.res", "OC_AH_026C.2.res"),  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)

Comment: OK I just added the code I am using to create df. Just tested again, works fine for me using data.table_1.9.6.

Comment: Did you try with the dput I have put in the question. There must be something wrong with the structure of my data...

Comment: There are no sequences of 1s in that data, only singleton 1s.

Comment: I've extended the dput. There aren't many consecutive 1's but if there is a singleton 1 then it should be converted to a zero anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95615/discussion-between-ken-benoit-and-sebastian-zeki).

Answer (score 1):

`f0(colNr,df)` contains the row numbers in which the column `df[,colNr]` should change to 0. `g(df)` is the converted data frame.

```
f0 <- function( colNr, df )
{
  col <- df[,colNr]

  n1 <- which( col == 1 )            # The `1`-rows.
  d0 <- which( diff(col) == 0 )      # Consecutive entries are equal.
  dc0 <- which( diff(df[,1]) == 0 )  # Same chromosome.

  m <- intersect( n1-1, intersect( d0, dc0 ) )

  return ( setdiff( 1:nrow(df), union(m,m+1) ) )
}

g <- function( df )
{
  for ( i in 3:ncol(df) ) { df[f0(i,df),i] <- 0 }  
  return ( df )
}
```

.
Example 1:

```
> df
   chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1    1    4324             0             1
2    1   23433             1             1
3    1   34436             1             0
4    1   64755             1             1
5    3     234             1             0
6    3     354             0             1
7    4    1666             0             1
8    4    4565             0             1
9    5   34777             0             1
10   7    2345             1             1
11   7    4567             1             1
> g(df)
   chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1    1    4324             0             1
2    1   23433             1             1
3    1   34436             1             0
4    1   64755             1             0
5    3     234             0             0
6    3     354             0             0
7    4    1666             0             1
8    4    4565             0             1
9    5   34777             0             0
10   7    2345             1             1
11   7    4567             1             1
>
```

Example 2:

```
> df
   chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1    1    4324             0             1
2    1   23433             1             1
3    1   34436             1             0
4    1   64755             1             1
5    3     234             1             0
6    3     354             1             1
7    4    1666             0             1
8    4    4565             1             1
9    5   34777             0             0
10   5    1234             1             0
11   7    2345             1             1
12   7    4567             1             1
> g(df)
   chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
1    1    4324             0             1
2    1   23433             1             1
3    1   34436             1             0
4    1   64755             1             0
5    3     234             1             0
6    3     354             1             0
7    4    1666             0             1
8    4    4565             0             1
9    5   34777             0             0
10   5    1234             0             0
11   7    2345             1             1
12   7    4567             1             1
>
```

Comment: When I run this I still get a few 1's on their own in the column. If they on their own they should be converted to zero.

Comment: The reason was that a row was completely untouched if in at least one column the condition to keep the "1" was satisfied. I fixed it now. The columns are handled separately.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution, building on my initial `ave` solution, which is also below:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
for (nam in names(dat)[3:4]) {
  dat[, 
    c(nam) := ((length((get(nam)==1)[get(nam)]) >= 2) & get(nam)==1)+0L,
    by=list(chr, cumsum(get(nam)==0))
  ]
}

#    chr leftPos OC_030_ST.res OC_031_WG.res
# 1:   1    4324             0             1
# 2:   1   23433             1             1
# 3:   1   34436             1             0
# 4:   1   64755             1             0
# 5:   3     234             0             0
# 6:   3     354             0             0
# 7:   4    1666             0             1
# 8:   4    4565             0             1
# 9:   5   34777             0             0
#10:   7    2345             1             1
#11:   7    4567             1             1
```

And my attempt using `ave` with a custom function:

```
fun <- function(x,grp,limit=2) { 
  runs <- ave(
    x==1,
    list(grp,cumsum(x==0)),
    FUN=function(g) length(g[g]) >= limit
  ) 
  as.numeric(runs & x==1)
}

lapply(dat[3:4], fun, grp=dat$chr)

#$OC_030_ST.res
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#
#$OC_031_WG.res
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

To overwrite your original data:

```
dat[3:4] <- lapply(dat[3:4], fun, grp=dat$chr)
```

Comment: This gives me the error Error in `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(c(nam), ((length((get(nam) == 1)[get(nam)]) >=  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)

Comment: @SebastianZeki - the error says nearly exactly what needs to be changed. Make `+0L` in my answer `+0`, as you have numeric data for your `0/1` columns instead of integer data, which I assumed you had.

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick can be to compare the original data set, say `df`, with its own copy `df[-1,]`, which essentially takes the first row off.

Comparing (columnswise) `df$OC_030_ST.res == df[-1,]$OC_030_ST.res` (likewise for the others) gives back a true table where each element is being compared with its next one.

Comment: I guess this fails for 1s at the end of a sequence and for the last row.

Comment: In principle it does, although the last element needs not be compared to anything else (being the last). But I agree that the last row always fails, should any other condition be introduced.

Comment: Are you sure? So what you are doing is actually compare the original with its neighbour next in line. So if this one is 1 and the next is 0 than it is a False, but it could be a True if the previous was a 1. But I guess it is how you define consecutive, but I guess in this case you want to include such a case and not void it. So 001110, you want to keep the third 1 in the serie and not throw it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make the next piece into a function and apply that per column per chromosome:

```
rand <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)

first=T
keep <- vector(length=length(rand),'numeric')
for (i in 1:length(rand)){
  if (first == T){first=F;if ((rand[i] == 1) & (rand[i+1] == 1)){keep[i] <- 1}} #check if first is 1 and had neigbour 1
  else if (rand[i] == 0){keep[i] <- 0} # if 0 than keep = 0
  else if (i == length(rand)){if (rand[i-1] == 1){keep[i] <- 1}} #if last than check if 1 and neighbour is 1 than keep = 1
  else if ((rand[i-1]==1) | (rand[i+1]==1)){keep[i] <- 1} #if 1 and has neighbour 1 than keep =1
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Not sure I know how to place this into a function kw<-apply(df,function(x){}) but then how to adapt what you have kindly written to place in here?